# How to position a set of div elements side by side?

Tags: html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I have placed two div elements contained in a form. My aim is to place the second div "App" side by side with the "Status" div like in the mock up below:

What I've tried so far is the following, setting the `align="right"` which positions the div on the extreme right.

Also I tried setting `style="margin-left:` which places the second div underneath and too far right of the first div.

**Question:**

Does anyone know how I can place the second div *in line* and *side by side* with the first div?

**Form markup:**

```
      <form action="" method="post">
                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">


                            <!-- SELECT STATUS STATIC-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="Current Status">Status</label>
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <select id="Status" name="Status" onchange="" class=" form-control">
                                        <option value="Down">Down</option>
                                        <option value="Up">Up</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <!-- SELECT APP STATIC-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-3 control-label"  for="App">App</label>
                                <div class="col-md-8" >
                                    <select id="App" name="App" onchange="" class=" form-control">
                                        <option value="SAP">SAP</option>
                                        <option value="JAP">JAP</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>            <!--END OF FORM ^^-->
```

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://jsfiddle.net/td6p74kq/ (50% 50%) Or do you want them right next to each other?

Comment: @HunterTurner I'm not very familiar with css. Does that code go in the site.css file and you then specify the class on the div elements in the form? Also I'd like them positioned closer together..

Comment: The best practice is to have your css in a separate file like your site.css rather than doing it inline. So like you said, you would reference the class (with a .) or the id (with a #) in the css file. Here's a little tutorial about getting started with CSS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set both divs to display: inline-block.

```
.form-group {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: You can put it into an external CSS file (recommended), or put it into style tag in <head>, or just use inline style like: <div class="form-group" style="display:inline-block">